# Cannot insert the value NULL into column C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I wrote an application in VS 2010 and after I inserted a new `datetime` value in the table the following error appears on saving the changes:

> 'Trips' table
>   Unable to modify table.
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EndDate', table 'C:\USERS\VALI\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\PROJECTS\TRIPPLANNER\TRIPPLANNER\TRIPPLANNER\APP_DATA\TRIPPLANNER.MDF.dbo.Tmp_Trips'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

[image]

This error disappears after I select the 'Allow Nulls' checkbox, but it must not accept a null value because I'll get another error on `<%= Model.EventDate.ToShortDateString() %>`.

I don't have experience with entity framework and please let me know if I need to add additional info for this issue..

Comment: There is no real question here. There is no problem either.

Comment: Just set the `EndDate` to a specific value, before you save the row - would that work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well either you want to accept null values or you don't. If you do you will need to handle that case when displaying them, for example:

```
<%= Model.EventDate == null ? "" : Model.EventDate.ToShortDateString() %>
```

Or for later versions of .NET (4.5+)

```
<%= Model.EventDate?.ToShortDateString() ?? "" %>
```

Comment: This helps me, thank you! I tried something like this before but with wrong sintax..